# "Error with Permissions-Policy header" getting after Chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, aurelia, security-policy

Getting following error from the console window after updating the chrome to version 88.0.4324.104

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Parse of permission policy failed because of errors reported by strctured header parser.
```

The application developed from ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Aurelia SPA. Tried to add following middleware to backend

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
           
{      
         context.Response.Headers.Add("Permission-Policy", "geolocation 'none';midi 'none';notifications 'none';push 'none';sync-xhr 'none';microphone 'none';camera 'none';magnetometer 'none';gyroscope 'none';speaker 'self';vibrate 'none';fullscreen 'self';payment 'none';");
         await next(); 
});
```

But still getting the console error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this same problem and it was solved this way:

The way you are creating the permissions policy is different.

```
Permissions-Policy: fullscreen=(self "https://example.com"), geolocation=*, camera=()
```

[Big changes since this was called Feature Policy](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/master/permissions-policy-explainer.md#appendix-big-changes-since-this-was-called-feature-policy)